# firebase-ui always shown `create account` page when I try to sign in with email and password

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

The email `915518319@qq.com` already registried and has been shown in firebase console user tab:
[image]

and now I try to sign in:
[image]

I clicked `Next` button, it say that i need to create a new account with this email:
[image]

what's more, I try to disable sign up: `disableSignUp.status = true` and try to sign again.
It shows that the email hasn't registried.

I was really very confused....

here is the firebase-ui config:

```
 const uiConfig: firebaseui.auth.Config = {
  callbacks: {
    signInSuccessWithAuthResult: (user) => handleLoginSuccess(user, false),
    uiShown: () => {},
  },
  // signInFlow: 'popup',
  signInOptions: [
    firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
    firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
    {
      provider: firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
      requireDisplayName: true,
      signInMethod: firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.EMAIL_PASSWORD_SIGN_IN_METHOD,
      disableSignUp: {
        status: true,
      },
    },
  ],
  // Terms of service url.
  tosUrl: '<your-tos-url>',
  // Privacy policy url.
  privacyPolicyUrl: '<your-privacy-policy-url>',
};

// sign in
getFirebaseAuthUI().start('#firebase-ui-auth-container', uiConfig);
```

Version:
"firebase": "^10.3.1",
"firebaseui": "^6.1.0",

Really very appreciate that if any one can help me with this issue!thank you !

Comment: Did you ever manage to resolve this issue?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you ever resolve it?